# Using openapi4j for request and response validation

Tags: spring-boot, openapi

I'm trying to write some test for one of my controllers that I've implemented in my project. I wanted to try implementing it with `openapi4j` library. I read some articles about it and how it could be useful.

Still, I'm having a hard time understanding how to implement it for my project. I read the `Usage` section in the `openapi4j` website, but to me, it seemed not very well documented. I'm wondering if some of you could point me out to some resource where the entire process is better documented.

Comment: I completely understand your frustration from searching for a good documentation, however such a question unfortunately goes against Stackoverflow policy. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, namely "Questions asking us to recommend or find a ... tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack.... Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 1):

More information can be found in the github project repository in the docs directory

[Docs](https://github.com/openapi4j/openapi4j/tree/master/docs)

Additionally, I advise you to pay attention to the tests in the repository. They show how the library is supposed to be used. And in general to read the project resources